# Limit to the number of methods in a web service

Tags: java, jax-ws, weblogic12c

When my web service class had 20 or so methods, everything worked fine. The web app deployed with no problems. Now, the number of methods has increased to 67, and deployment on Weblogic has become extremely slow, even to the point of timing out.

My question is, is there a limit to the number of methods in a web service? What are the best practices with regards to number of web service methods per service class?

Thanks

Edit: I understand having 67 methods might be a code smell, but is that really the cause of this?

My web services are declared in an interface:

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
public interface ComponentService {
......
}
```

And the methods are implemented as such:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "compservice", endpointInterface = "org.telway.service.ComponentService")
public class ComponentServiceImpl implements ComponentService {
.....
}
```

Comment: Any class with 67 methods is a code smell. You should distribute them into other classes, keeping good design in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no strict definition of how many is to many. That is something experience tells you.

However chances are that if your web service has 67 methods it's breaking the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Let's say that you're building a blogging platform where a user can signup, login, comment on others posts, write posts etc. etc. Then you shouldn't create a class that handles all of that. Instead try to separate the classes so that maybe one class handles logins, another class handles signups and so on.

That way you'll have a system that is much easier understand and change in the future.

As for why your deploy is slow, I have no idea.